# State doesn't have variable in react redux, variable not found on state

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, action, store

I'm using React redux to store state across my application.

I have the following component:

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setCompleted } from '../actions/completedActions';

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Login'
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      completedChallenges: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button onPress={this._handlePressAsync}>
            Hit me!
          <Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _handlePressAsync = async () => {

    fetch(API + userInfo.id)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJSON) => {
      console.log(responseJSON);
      for (var i = 0; i < responseJSON.length; i++) {
        this.props.dispatch(setCompleted(responseJSON[i]));
      }
    })

  };

}

});

export default connect()(LoginScreen);
```

My setCompleted action is as follows:

```js
export const setCompleted = (completedChallenge) => {
  console.log("completed challenge in action");
  console.log(completedChallenge);
  return {
    type: 'SET_COMPLETED',
    completedChallenge
  }
}
```

And my completedReducer is as follows:

```js
const completedReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  console.log("completedReducer");
  console.log(state);
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_COMPLETED':
      return [
        ...state,
          {
            completedChallenges: [
              ...state[completedChallenges],
              action.completedChallenge
            ]
          }
        ]
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default completedReducer
```

I have added the reducer to the `combineReducers()` function. When I run the code and hit the button, the execution goes all the way through to the reducer and then I get the error, `"[Unhandled Promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: completedChallenges]"`; It makes sense since the state prints as `[]`. But how do I add completedChallenges to the state?

Thanks

Comment: `...state[completedChallenges]` in your reducer is a variable. You probably mean `state.completedChallenges` or `state['completedChallenges']`

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the comment, I now get "Array.from requires an array-like object not null or undefined". It seems it's still not set to anything? Should I not be initialising it with an empty array?

Comment: Sorry, I think I've found the answer now here http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html, where they set the initial state. Apologies for being such a noob.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your reducer you meant :

```
return [
  ...state, 
  { completedChallenges: [
    ...state[action.completedChallenge], 
    action.completedChallenge
   ] } 
]
```

Even I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to do... What reducer shape do you expect?

Also, why do you have a state in your component ?

Comment: Hi Jalil, what I'm trying to do is add the list of completed components, rather than overwriting it. E.g: state 1: has completed challenges [A,B,C], we then complete challenge D, and state 2: should then become [A,B,C,D] rather than just D.

Comment: Then why not just `return [ ...state, action.completedChallenge]` to add the new challenge to the list ?